# How does an embedded google maps send data despite same origin policy?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, same-origin-policy

I was wondering how google maps accomplishes to send data to their servers when the map is embedded on some remote host. For example I can still set a marker on an embedded map. How do they dodge the same origin policy?

Thank you and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maps are embedded on your website but they are still on a Google server, domain ... on the same domain they need to send data to.

Comment: Ah I see. How is this roughly implemented? Suppose I embedded my google map which leads to a script being loaded via JSONP. Do at this point in time all client side scripts have access to the remote domain which was "introduced" by loading the google script? Or do only those procedures invoked by the remotely loaded script have access to the remote domain?